# wp_insert_user if user exists

Tags: user-registration, wp-api

I have been at this for almost two hours, i'm sure i'm close, but can't find the nudge to make it work.
I built a module from scratch to import users from a csv file, the user creation is working fine, and i'm happy with that.

For the process to be convenient, i want to be able to update the users too, and always work with the same csv file. The wp_update_user does nothing, no error, but values from array are not updated. update_user_meta does not work either. i suppose it is the way i return the $user_id, since the ID is not included in the array...

```
         $userdata = array(      
            'user_login' => $username,
            'nickname' => $username,
            'user_nicename' => $user_nicename,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'first_name' => $prenom,
            'last_name' => $nom,
            'user_registered' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
            'display_name' => $username,
            'show_admin_bar_front' => false,
            'role' => 'subscriber',
            'admin_color' => "fresh",
            'rich_editing' => "true", 
            );

        // check if user exists
        if (username_exists($username)) {
            $user_id = $userdata[0]->ID;
            $user_id = wp_update_user( $userdata );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'region', $region );
        } else {
        // create new user
            $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
            wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'both' );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'region', $region );
        }
```

Edit : So here is the fix, in case anyone is looking for a similar issue :

```
    if (username_exists($username)) {
        $the_user = get_user_by('login', $username);
        $user_id = $the_user->ID;

       if (!is_wp_error( $user_id )){
           $push_id = array('ID' => $user_id);
           $merge = array_merge($userdata, $push_id);
           $user_id = wp_update_user( $merge );
           update_user_meta( $user_id, 'region', $region );
       }
       else {                                       
       $html_update = "Broken";
       }
     } else {
     // create new user
        $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'both' );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'region', $region );
     }
```

Thank you birgire, it helped me find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating a user with:

```
$user_id = wp_update_user( $userdata );
```

you need to have the user ID set within `$userdata`.

Also make sure to validate the `$user_id` output of `wp_update_user()` as it can be either an integer or an instance of `WP_Error`, before using it in `update_user_meta()`.

One can use `is_wp_error( $user_id )` to check if `$user_id` is an instance of the `WP_Error` class.

PS:

Make sure to have a look at PHP errors while developing.

When the new fatal error protection (WSOD) [kicks in](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/01/14/php-site-health-mechanisms-in-5-1/) after 5.1, one might need to disable it by defining the constant:

```
WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER
```

as `true` in `wp-config.php` on dev installs.

Comment: So i found the correct way to return the correct $user_id, i created a new array containing the user_id, and merged it with the $userdata array. There probably is a cleaner way to do i, but it works!

Comment: I'm also validating the $user_id, did i do it right ? $html_update is called later in my html page template

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Note that the `get_user_by()` can return an `WP_User` object or `false`. The `wp_update_user()`/`wp_insert_user()` functions can return a user `ID` or `WP_Error` object. So you need to validate according to that. E.g. `is_wp_error( $user_id )` will return `false` when `$user_id` is `false`.

Comment: So i guess a `if($user_id != false && !is_wp_error( $user_id))` could do the job for validating?

Comment: Im on mobile so to explain it in short,  you are not validating whats needed. Walk through each line of your code and check if eg WP_Error can go through undetected. Currently it can.

Comment: So lookup in the Codex what the functions, you use, can output to see what needs to be validated. Hope it helps.